# How to perform DB bitwise queries in Django?

Tags: django, bit-manipulation

How can I perform bitwise queries on the DB with Django?
I haven't found anything about it in the docs.
Should I retrieve a queryset and then filter programmically?

If you're interested, I use bitwise ops as an alternative to **IN()** statements in very large and complex queries, in order to improve performance.
I have a DB containing millions of items (records). Some fields use binary representation of an item property.
For example: the **Color** field can have multiple values, so it is structured like so:

```
0001 - Red
0010 - Green
0100 - Blue
1000 - White
```

(these are binary values)
So if an item has Red and Blue colors, the **Color** field will contain `0101`.
When a user queries the DB, I use bitwise-OR to find matches (instead of **IN()** which is very slow).

Answer (score 12):

You can perform database-level bitwise operations with [F objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

If field is non-negative, it means that condition `field & mask > 0` can be re-written as `(field > 0) AND (field >= (field & mask))`. If you want to check if all bits of `mask` apply (`(field & mask) == mask`), you can build previous expression for each bit and then merge conditions via sql `AND`. Please see example how it can be done. (Custom QuerySet is just for convenience. If you use old django versions you can implement `has_one_of` and `has_all` as separate functions or classmethods, or better [PathThroughManager](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#passthroughmanager)). Note `1 * F` is a workaround to force parenthesis over bitwise operation, otherwise django (as for version 1.5) will produce bad sql (`colors >= colors & mask`, comparison has higher priority, so it will mean `TRUE & mask`)

```
import operator
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q, F

_bit = lambda x: 2**(x-1)
RED = _bit(1)
GREEN = _bit(2)
BLUE = _bit(3)
WHITE = _bit(4)


class ItemColorsQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def has_one_of(self, colors):
        """
            Only those that has at least one of provided colors
        """
        return self.filter(
            colors__gt=0,
            # field value contains one of supplied color bits
            colors__lt=F('colors') + (1 * F('colors').bitand(reduce(operator.or_, colors, 0)))
        )

    def has_all(self, colors):
        """
            Has all provided colors (and probably others)
        """
        # filter conditions for all supplied colors: 
        # each one is "field value has bit that represents color"
        colors_q = map(lambda c: Q(colors__gte=1 * F('colors').bitand(c)), colors)
        # one complex Q object merged via sql AND:
        # colors>0 and all color-bit conditions
        filter_q = reduce(operator.and_, colors_q, Q(colors__gt=0))
        return self.filter(filter_q)


class Item(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    # can handle many colors using bitwise logic. Zero means no color is set.
    colors = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    objects = ItemColorsQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Comment: Yes, that's was my own idea, I found this question while searching for solution, and when I finally implemented it in our project, just came back to share the idea.

Comment: I think it does not work if `F('colors').bitand(color)` is `0`. I used `flags__lt=(F("flags")+1*F("flags").bitand(flag)))` instead

Comment: @Elisha Looks like you miss parentheses around +1

Comment: @IvanKlass maybe, I don't remember now what I tried to do.Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. For example, imagine the value of the field of the object in the db is `1010`. You filter for `1000` -> correct, since the value in the db is larger than the value of the bit-wise `and`. But if you filter for `0001`, you will also have the item returned, since `1010 & 0001 = 0000 < 1010`. Or am I wrong? In my case only @gaozhidf's answer using `annotate` worked!

Comment: Downvoted because it is incorrect, as @MoRe has observed as well

Answer (score 11):

same like `@Ivan Klass`,

You can use `bitand` or `bitor` from [django orm F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model),

```
# filter Red and Blue(0101)
Color.objects.annotate(
  color_filter=F('color').bitand(0101)
).filter(color_filter__gte=0101)

 # filter Red or Blue(0101)
Color.objects.annotate(
  color_filter=F('color').bitand(0101)
).filter(color_filter__gt=0)
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `.filter(color_filter=0101)` in the first case for "Red **and** Blue"?

Comment: @MoRe, yes, you can just filter "Red and Blue"(0101) with `.filter(color_filter=0101)`, and filter those includes "Red and Blue"(like 0101, 0111) with `.filter(color_filter__gte=0101)`

Answer (score 10):

For postgres db you might use [.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra) params with django orm.

For example:

```
SomeModel.objects.extra(where=['brand_label & 3 = 3'])
```

Answer (score 7):

Check [django-bitfield](https://github.com/disqus/django-bitfield) , it works well w/ PostgreSQL (probably also well MySQL)

Comment: Hi, I'm actually using MySQL (thinking of migrating to MongoDB, but it doesn't support bitwise queries ATM)

Comment: @user1102018 I've just checked the code, it should work on MySQL, because it uses normal integer field and normal bitwise & and | which are all supported by MySQL.