# Django query that filters on calculated fields, searching for character within string

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a django model that describes a cyclical status between two dates.  It looks something like:

```py
class OnCallCycle(models.Model):
    crew = models.ForeignKey(Crew, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
    cycle = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

where `start` and `end` are the inclusive start and end date of the cycle, and `cycle` is a string representing the on call status cycle using one character per day.  E.g.- if you had a 12 day cycle where the first 6 days were on (represented by a `P`), and the last 6 days were off (represented by an `N`, `cycle` would look like: `PPPPPPNNNNNN`.  If the number of days between `start` and `end` are greater than the length of the cycle, it repeats.  Thus, given an OnCallCycle instance, `occ`, one can calculate the on call status for a given date, `d` (known to be between `start` and `end`) by:

```py
delta = (d-occ.start).days
status = occ.cycle[delta % len(occ.cycle)]
```

Is there any way to do this within a query for a given date, `d`?  I would like to do something like this:

```py
active_cycles = OnCallCycle.objects.filter(
    start__lte=d,
    end__gte=d
).filter(
    # Find all OnCallCycles where the cycle status for date d is not 'N'
)
```

I am using Postgres for my database, if that changes anything.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression filter to get the particular status. 
The expression should be something like that `^.{8}P` where 8 is the position and P is the letter you want to find.

I would suggest however to encode the status in bits. The regular expressions tend to differ between database providers and version, which makes them quirky. 
If you decide to play with the bits check this:
[How to perform DB bitwise queries in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921221/how-to-perform-db-bitwise-queries-in-django)

Comment: Bits wouldn't work, as there are multiple statuses (I just kept it to P an N for this example, but there are several others as well).  The other question I have re: what you're suggesting- the location in 'cycle' is dependent on the length of cycle, the start date, and the date we're looking up.  Is there any way to do that delta/index calculation within the query?

Comment: no, you need to pre-set the index and the state and pass those to the regex. Also if you have multiple statuses why not simply drop the field and add a log table, where you can store executions? if you want to check against the length of the status string check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314168/django-filter-on-the-basis-of-text-length